# Rewriting the code of DataGridViewColumn to insert a picturebox which opens a dialog

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am a beginner. How can I rewrite the code of a cell in a datagridview using datagridviewcolumn and its derived classes? The code is in Visual C# 
I have some examples which depicts a DateTimePicker and TextButtonColumn, found on the net, but i need another events.

The main idea is to show a PictureBox with a default image in the middle of the screen and when the user clicks, then it opens a OpenFileDialog to load an image. Finally the control saves the image into a property, and changes the icon for the image selected or can use another image  which represents a filled cell.

Is it difficult?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a solution for your problem but try it with a [DataGridViewImageColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx).
You can use the [CellClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick)-Event of the DataGridView. There you have to detect if one of your image cell is clicked.
For changing the image you can create a new OpenFileDialog.

I hope this helps you.